# Find center of multiple locations in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have just copied the code on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) and applied my latitude and longitudes. However, the latitudes and longitudes will be dynamic, and the `center` of the map will change depending on the latitudes and longitudes of the locations.

The following is the code from the other question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var locations = [
                ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
                ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
                ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
                ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
                ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
            ];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

So my question is, how could I know the center of the map when having dynamic locations. I've tried leaving the `center` blank but the map didn't load.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

First you can create a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object by including all the dynamically generated locations. Use the extend method to include the points. Then you can get the center of the bound using the getCenter method.

**UPDATE:**

Code:

```
var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  bound.extend( new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]) );

  // OTHER CODE
}

console.log( bound.getCenter() );
```

**Illustration:**

[image]

Comment: Add map.fitBounds(bound) to the code to fit the map zoom and center UI within bounds.

Comment: a demo of the explained above - https://jsfiddle.net/3rhjwc5b/1/ -- thanks @Salman!

Comment: That works pretty well! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this by averaging the latitudes and averaging the longitudes and using those averages as my center.

Example:

```
self.adjustPosition = function () {
    var lat = 0, lng = 0;

    if (self.nearbyPlaces().length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < self.nearbyPlaces().length; i++) {
        lat += self.nearbyPlaces()[i].latitude;
        lng += self.nearbyPlaces()[i].longitude;
    }

    lat = lat / self.nearbyPlaces().length;
    lng = lng / self.nearbyPlaces().length;

    self.map.setCenter(new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
};
```

Comment: I'm using your logic with ruby and it's working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not work because it will average the numbers and not get the "middle" of the numbers (lat/long). Think of it like this, you have 6 points in the US, one in CA and 5 on east coast spread north and south. The 5 on east coast weight the average to the right(east) on the map and your center point would be (East to West) around Georgia. If you wanted to avoid using getCenter you would want to find the highest and the lowest of east direction (lat +/- and long +/-) and find the middle of each direction once you had the extremes.

Answer (score 0):

```
private LatLng computeCentroid(List<LatLng> points) {
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
int n = points.size();

for (LatLng point : points) {
    latitude += point.latitude;
    longitude += point.longitude;
}

return new LatLng(latitude/n, longitude/n);
```

}