# Automatic centering of Google maps on points

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<style>
#map_canvas {
    border:1px solid transparent;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 padding_all_right_4">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding_all_3">
   <h2 class="h2">Atrakcje w okolicy</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding_all_2">
   <a href ="#" class="obj-1" id="obj-1">
      <div class="apartament_atrakcje">Atrakcja 1 pl</div>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding_all_2">
   <a href ="#" class="obj-2" id="obj-2">
      <div class="apartament_atrakcje">Atrakcja 2 PL</div>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding_all_0">
<div class="apartament_mapa">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
   var locations = [
                                               ['Atrakcja 1 pl', 51.73925413, 19.51309225, 1],
                                               ['Atrakcja 2 PL', 53.41475000, 14.60220358, 2],
                                           ];
   var map;
   var markers = [];

   function init(){
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
           zoom: 10,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       });

       var num_markers = locations.length;
       for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
           markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
               map: map,
               html: locations[i][0],
               id: i,
           });

           google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   id: this.id,
                   content:this.html,
                   position:this.getPosition()
               });
               google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function(){
                   markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
               });
               this.setVisible(false);
               infowindow.open(map);
           });
       }
   }

   init();

</script>
```

The script displays 2 points on the google map.
I have a problem with centering the map on these points. Currently, I enter the coordinates of the centering of the map in the page code, however points on the map are added from the CMS and must center automatically :(

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to center on one point? [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) answer will do that for you.

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Else if what you need is to center on the 'center' of those two points. You'll need to calculate the center point between those two and then center on this new LatLong. For that you can check [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/) 
and this post of stackoverflow: [Find center of multiple locations in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634199/find-center-of-multiple-locations-in-google-maps)

Comment: I would like to center on many points (1,2,5,10)

Comment: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
zoom: 10, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }); map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)); - this is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634199/find-center-of-multiple-locations-in-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

You could use setCenter()

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

eg for center on the first marker

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]));
```

Comment: Can you show me how to use your code on my code?

Comment: answer  updated .

Comment: This code centers only on 1 point

Comment: @traffick .. change the center for each point during a loop have not sense  .. .. once you have draw you markers the set the center where you prefer  .,. the first .. the last or a middle points ..

Comment: can you show me sample?

Comment: simply at the out of the loop  add  the code in my answer ..

Comment: I tried and centers me on Łódź (one marker). Do you center the map on 2 markers?